# Incrementing values with Vuex Module Decorators and TS

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-module-decorators

I'm having a big issue when it comes to incrementing data.

```js
@Module
class Mod extends VuexModule {
   public value = 2; // this is only accessible within a MutationAction when using this.state.value, but has a lot of type errors.

   @MutationAction({ mutate: ["value"] })
   async valueIncrement(): Promise<Record<"value", number>> {
      const req: AxiosRequest = await axios.get("...randomValue/");

      return {
         value: this.value += req.data // this doesn't work because this.value is undefined
      }
   }
}
```

It seems `MutationAction` doesn't have access to the module state?

Another solution that I found, which looks like a workaround, is to set `(this.state as this).value`.

Is there some way to access the state directly from a `MutationAction`, some extra configuration maybe?

Answer (score 0):

as per [MutationActions source code](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators/blob/master/src/mutationaction.ts#L29) , the function is called with store's context as 'this' , so i believe you will find value at this.state.value

Comment: I wasn't able to use Actions, so I started using getModule and it worked out fine.

Comment: used getModule inside a module ?

Comment: No, outside the module.